# Ansible: Change script value (.sh file) via yml playbook

Tags: shell, ansible, sh

For example, the relevant part of my playbook looks like this:

```
tasks:
  - name: test
    script: ../test.sh
    ...
```

And for my test.sh there is this one line of code that will execute a python script as such:

```
python run.py --inputvar hello
```

Is there a way to change the inputvar value within the .sh file from "hello" to something else from the playbook?

Edit:
Appreciate @seshadri_c 's help on this. Guess this question shouldve been tagged under shell scripts.

Comment: You can run Python scripts directly with the `script` module, as one of examples on the [documentation](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/2.9/modules/script_module.html#examples) suggests. Is having a shell script mandatory?

Comment: @seshadri_c preferably so for standardization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest way to parse arguments in a shell script is using positional arguments - `$1`, `$2`, etc.

Given a `test.sh` script with:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

python run.py --inputvar $1
```

And running it as:

```
/bin/bash test.sh arg1
```

will pass the value of `$1` to `run.py` as `--inputvar arg1`.

Same thing can be run from Ansible task:

```yaml
tasks:
  - name: test
    script: ../test.sh arg1
```

Answer (score 1):

There are more options.

1. The first one might be [*lineinfile*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/lineinfile_module.html), e.g. the task below is idempotent

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: test.sh
        regex: '^python run.py --inputvar (.*)$'
        line: 'python run.py --inputvar {{ my_var|default("hello") }}'
```

gives

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] *******************************************************
ok: [localhost]
```

If you define the variable *my_var* (See [Variable precedence: Where should I put a variable?](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-precedence-where-should-i-put-a-variable))

```yaml
my_var: hello world
```

The task will change the line in the file. (Running the playbook with options *--check --diff*)

```yaml
TASK [lineinfile] ********************************************************
--- before: test.sh (content)
+++ after: test.sh (content)
@@ -1,3 +1,3 @@
 #!/usr/bin/sh
 
-python run.py --inputvar hello
+python run.py --inputvar hello world

changed: [localhost]
```

---

The next option might be [*template*](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/collections/ansible/builtin/template_module.html), e.g. the template *test.sh.j2* and the task below give the same results

```yaml
shell> cat test.sh.j2
#!/usr/bin/sh

python run.py --inputvar {{ my_var|default("hello") }}
```

```yaml
    - template:
        src: test.sh.j2
        dest: test.sh
```